# Devise : undefined method `user_signed_in? Didn't know why?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Please help i am using rails 3.2.11 and devise 2.0.6 but when i am trying to run my project i am getting an error **undefined method `user_signed_in?' for Class**
i have done lot of google but didnt find any solution.!

Below is my **application trace**

```
NoMethodError in Home#index

Showing /home/amits/RailsWorkspace/Myapp/app/views/home/index.html.haml where line #3 raised:

undefined method `user_signed_in?' for #<#<Class:0xbb1f3f4>:0xbae60b8>

Extracted source (around line #3):

1: %h2= (t :welcome) + " Myapp"
2: 
3: - if user_signed_in?
4:   = link_to (I18n.t :customers), user_root_path
5:   / %li
6:   / = link_to (I18n.t :sign_out), destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete

Rails.root: /home/amits/RailsWorkspace/Myapp
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/home/index.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_home_index_html_haml___806580830_97751900'

Request

Parameters:

None

Show session dump

Show env dump
Response

Headers:

None
```

and my gem file is as follows

Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'heroku'

gem 'pg'

gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails', :group => :development

gem 'rmagick'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.0'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem "devise", "~> 2.0.0"
gem 'devise_aes_encryptable'
# version added so that the gem version will be stable at this point.
gem 'geokit', '1.5.0'
gem 'geokit-rails3', '0.1.5'
```

My Home controller

**Homescontroller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index

  end
end
```

My user model

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :token_authenticatable, :omniauthable

 # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :sign_in_count

end
```

**Rotes.rb**

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  root to: "home#index"

end
```

Please help me....

Comment: have you called :authenticate_user! in your controller?

Comment: Yes i have it my home controller check my edited question

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 'clear_helpers' method in ApplicationController as it might block sometimes Devise to load his helpers.

Comment: I found the issue there is an problem with geokit and geokit-rails3 please check my gem file.